# How to add Glassfish 5.0 server in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

We have a java application on netbeans that's using Glassfish server 4.1. We recently conducted a scan we got recommendation that we should update Glassfish server to the latest version because v4.1 has vulnerability issues. I download Glassfish server 5.0 which in zip, I unzipped and navigate inside the folders. I'am able to reach the admin console `localhost:4848` but when I tried adding Glassfish server from tools in netbeans it tells me that not a valid Glassfish server installation. Checked everywhere online couldn't find a solution to this, I don't know how to go about this, could anybody help please???

Comment: Hmm maybe you need a recent Netbeans version? Did you try with 11.1? I'd also suggest to use Glassfish 5.1 or even Payara if security fixes are important to you.

Comment: I'm downloading them already, let me try this

Comment: @ChristophJohn There is absolutely no need to use a more recent version of NetBeans to successfully add GlassFish 5; it works fine with 8.2.

Comment: @skomisa Fair enough, I just trusted that he could successfully unpack the Glassfish distribution and have Netbeans point to that. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than research and guess what your specific problem might be, it is far easier just to start over since the entire process of downloading and configuring Glassfish 5 in NetBeans 8.2 only takes a couple of minutes.

Step 1:

- **Tools > Add Server**
- Select *GlassFish Server*, enter a suitable name in the **Name** field and click **Next >**

  [image: screen1]

Step 2

- On the **Add Server Instance** screen, click the **Browse...** button.
- Navigate to your existing Glassfish 5 installation and select the top level directory, and click **Choose**.

  [image: screen2]

Step 3

- Having done that you should see a message stating "*Detected a Glassfish Server 5.0 install...*" as shown in the screen shot below.
- If you don't see that message (and apparently you are getting "*Not a valid GlassFish Server installation.*") then simply [download Glassfish 5 again](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download), unzip it to a new directory, and use that installation instead.
- Click the check box for "*I have read and accept...*" and click **Next >**.
  [image: screen3]

Step 4

- Accept the default values for the *Domain Location* settings and click **Finish**.

  [image: screen4]

Step 5

- Now open **Tools > Servers** and select the server you just added. The screen should look similar to this:

  [image: screen5]

I just tried this and it worked fine using NetBeans 8.2, Oracle Glassfish 5 and JDK 8.

Comment: For Mac OS users who are working with netbeans 8.2 and want to add glassfish5. If you keep getting the error message "Not a valid Glassfish server installation" then you have to enter manually the relative path of the glassfish5 server. Note that the glassfish5 folder needs to be put into your netbeans installation folder.